# How to define @@system_time_zone as default value of a column of an existing table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to define @@system_time_zone as the default value of a column I am trying to add to an existing table.
e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD COLUMN TIME_ZONE CHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT @@system_time_zone;
```

This throws me a MySQL syntax error. I tried enclosing @@system_time_zone within single quotes. I am right now splitting this into two, as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD COLUMN TIME_ZONE CHAR(64) NOT NULL;

UPTATE T1 SET TIME_ZONE=@@system_time_zone;
```

This works but it is obvious that this is not an ideal solution. I have tried searching Google/StackOverFlow but to no avail. Can anyone let me know if there is a correct syntax that can achieve this/any other alternative by which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [restriction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) in MySQL:

`The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression`

But `@@` and `@` are expressions which is used to get values for system or local variables. And they are not constant. They can be changed run-time.

Your approach is fine, but if you really want to use system variable you can use dynamic SQL like:

```
set @q = concat('alter table t1 add column time_zone char(64) not null default ', quote(@@system_time_zone));

prepare stmt from @q;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Per @lanzz advice:
In the last code block `@@system_time_zone` become a constant instead of dynamic variables. And if time zone will be changed in the future default value for this column will stay intact.

Comment: You probably need a trailing space at the end of the statement (after `not null default`); also it might be good to point that with this approach, the default value is _the current system time zone at the time of creation of the table_, not at the time of insertion into the table; i.e. if you later change the system time zone, the column default will still be the old system time zone.

Comment: @lanzz, it's true. Because it became a constant.

Comment: I know it is, I'm trying to help you improve your answer for the benefit of future readers. It would be good to include that caveat in the actual answer body, because it is likely that the OP would expect to always have the current system time zone as default for that column.